# Относительные прилагательные от имён собственных — с прописной или со строчной буквы?

Tags: орфография, прописная-строчная, прилагательные

Когда мы превращаем название государства или топоним в прилагательное, то нужно писать его со строчной или с прописной буквы?

Примеры:

- японский городовой или Японский городовой? (имя собственное — Япония);
- камчатский товарищ или Камчатский товарищ? (имя собственное — Камчатка);
- французская консерва или Французская консерва? (имя собственное — Франция).

Comment: Какие субстантивированные имена имеете в виду?. ГОРОДОВОЙ; м. В России с 1862 г. до 1917 г.: нижний чин городской полиции.  Япония — это существительное, имя собственное, японский — это относительное прилагательное. Но вот само сочетание "японский городовой" имеет интересную историю (все буквы строчные) 
 
 https://pikabu.ru/story/yaponskiy_gorodovoy_istoriya_vyirazheniya_dlya_tekh_kto_khochet_znat_940509

Comment: @Sharon Это потому что я всё перепутал. Я имел ввиду относительные прилагательные. То есть превращение имени собственного (существительного) в прилагательное, а не наоборот превращение в существительное. Счас поправлю вопрос. Спасибо, что обратили на это внимание.

Comment: https://orfogrammka.ru/тотальный_диктант/правописание-прилагательных-образованных-от-географических-названий/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В ПАС под редакцией Лопатина:

> **§ 177.** Прилагательные, образованные от географических названий, пишутся с прописной буквы, если они являются частью составных наименований — географических и административно-территориальных (см. § 169), индивидуальных имен людей (§ 157), названий исторических эпох и событий (§ 179), учреждений (§ 189), архитектурных и др. памятников (§ 186, 194), военных округов и фронтов. В остальных случаях они пишутся со строчной буквы. Ср., напр.: *невские берега, невские набережные* и *Александр Невский, Невский проспект, Невская битва; донское казачество* и *Дмитрий Донской, Донской монастырь; московские улицы, кварталы, московский образ жизни* и *Московская область, Московский вокзал* (в Петербурге), *Московская государственная консерватория; казанские достопримечательности* и *Казанский кремль, Казанский университет, Казанский собор* (в Петербурге, Москве); *северокавказская природа* и *Северо-Кавказский регион, Северо-Кавказский военный округ; 1-й Белорусский фронт, Потсдамская конференция, Санкт-Петербургский монетный двор, Великая Китайская стена, Большой Кремлёвский дворец.*

Ни городовые, ни товарищи, ни консервы к категориям, указанным в первой части правила, никак не относятся, поэтому прилагательные с этими словами пишутся со строчной буквы.

Самые известные похожие выражения (во всяком случае, для меня) — это ***т**амбовский волк* и ***к**итайское предупреждение*.
Но — заглянем в Нацкорпус РЯ:

*― Молчи, **японский** городовой* (Петр Алешковский. Жизнеописание Хорька);
*― Товарищи! ― воскликнул Антоша и в паузе заметил в третьем ряду партера морду матерого партработника, перекошенную ухмылкой: дескать, **тамбовский** волк тебе товарищ* (Василий Аксенов. Таинственная страсть);
*― Ты просто лакаешь, падла! Делаю тебе первое серьезное **китайское** предупреждение* (Эдвард Радзинский. Наш Декамерон);
*С чисто **немецкой** пунктуальностью одно за другим следовали длиннющие перечисления ингредиентов...* (Еремей Парнов. Александрийская гемма).

[Правила употребления прописных и строчных букв](http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=81#pp81)

Comment: Вы легенда. Спасибо.

Comment: Ого!.. Прям растерялась. И Вам поклон за высокую оценку. Окрылили, право слово.